# Changing CBitmap storage on clipboard from OpenClipboard()/CloseClipboard() to COleDataSource (MFC)

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, clipboard, ole, cbitmap

I have an MFC app that stores a `CBitmap` on the clipboard using `OpenClipboard()`/`SetClipboardData()`/`CloseClipboard()`:

```
if(OpenClipboard())
{
    if(EmptyClipboard())
    {
        SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, pBitmap->m_hObject);
        CloseClipboard();
    }
}
// Error reported omitted for brevity.
```

It works well, however elsewhere the app stores custom data on the clipboard using `COleDataSource`:

```
COleDataSource* pOleSource = new COleDataSource;
pOleSource->CacheGlobalData(uiRiggerFormat, hMem);
pOleSource->SetClipboard();
```

That works well, too.

I would like to change the storage of the `CBitmap` to use `COleDataSource` so I can put both the `CBitmap` and the custom data on the clipboard at the same time (and the app receiving the paste can decide which format it wants).

I tried using `COleDataSource` like this (passing the CBitmap's hObject), but it crashes on paste. It seems the object's size on the clipboard is 0.

```
COleDataSource* pOleSource = new COleDataSource;
pOleSource->CacheGlobalData(CF_BITMAP, pBitmap->m_hObject);
pOleSource->SetClipboard();
// FYI, I do not free pBitmap.
```

I *suspect* the problem is the `pBitmap` (which I am not freeing) isn't in global memory. I barely know what that means.

Based on code I found elsewhere, I tried to move the `pBitmap` to global memory like this:

```
BITMAP bmpInfo;
pBitmap->GetBitmap(&bmpInfo);
int size = bmpInfo.bmWidthBytes * bmpInfo.bmHeight;
BYTE* pBits = new BYTE[size];
pBitmap->GetBitmapBits(size, pBits);
HGLOBAL hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, size);
LPVOID pMem = GlobalLock(hMem);
memcpy(pMem, pBits, size);

// Store it.
COleDataSource* pOleSource = new COleDataSource;
ASSERT(pOleSource);
pOleSource->CacheGlobalData(CF_BITMAP, hMem);
pOleSource->SetClipboard();
```

That no longer crashes on paste, but the image doesn't appear. I *suspect* that's because the size I am calculating (which is the bitmap bits) isn't the same as the size of the entire bitmap that needs to be copied to the clipboard.

Can you straighten me out? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I came across the following code (and see that Igor suggested this approach):

```
tagSTGMEDIUM* pStorageMedium = new tagSTGMEDIUM;
memset(pStorageMedium, 0, sizeof(tagSTGMEDIUM));
pStorageMedium->tymed = TYMED_GDI;
pStorageMedium->hBitmap = HBITMAP(*pDestBitmap);
COleDataSource* pOleSource = new COleDataSource;
pOleSource->CacheData(CF_BITMAP, pStorageMedium);
pOleSource->SetClipboard();
delete pStorageMedium;
```

This works! However, the `pDC` (`CDC` pointer) I create when creating the bitmap (as shown below; error checking not shown for brevity) results in a memory leak.

```
CClientDC cdc(this);
CDC* pDc = new CDC();
pDc->CreateCompatibleDC(&cdc)
pBitmap->CreateCompatibleBitmap(&cdc, iBitmapWidth, iBitmapHeight);
const CBitmap* pOldDestBitmap = pDc->SelectObject(pBitmap);
CDC dcBitmap;
dcBitmap.CreateCompatibleDC(pDc);
const CBitmap* pOldBitmap = dcBitmap.SelectObject(&bmpBitmap);
pDc->BitBlt(0, 0, iBitmapWidth, iBitmapHeight, &dcBitmap, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

If I delete the `pDC` (to prevent the leak), the bitmap can't be pasted from the clipboard.

What can I do to prevent the leak?

Thanks! (And thanks, Igor Tandetnik!)

Comment: For a bitmap (or any data not represented with `HGLOBAL`), you need to use `COleDataSource::CacheData`. That takes `STGMEDIUM` structure which, among other things, has `hBitmap` member.